# How to display comments list by order when clicking on newest or oldest link?

Tags: wp-query, comments

0 down vote favorite

I have a wordpress single post where I have comment system - [Live Site](http://oryxtesting.com/events/teaching-event/)

And I have two links one is: 1. newest 2. oldest

The thing I want is when I will click on newest it will display the comments list in newest order and if I click on oldest it will display the comments list from oldest to newest.

Any simple solution is fine (though I prefer using ajax but no need for ajax right now). GET and POST method will be fine.

Any clue?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: see the live site: http://oryxtesting.com/events/teaching-event/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the comments.php file from your theme. Find the following line (or similar)

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
```

Add this lines just above it

```
if (isset($_GET['comOrder']) && $_GET['comOrder'] == 'Newest' )
    $comments = array_reverse($comments, true);
```

so your code looks like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['comOrder']) && $_GET['comOrder'] == 'Newest' )
        $comments = array_reverse($comments, true);
foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
```

and then make sure your `newest first` like points to your current location with `?comOrder=Newest`

**UPDATE:**

In case you are using `wp_list_comments` then simply add `reverse_top_level` parameter set to true when newest first link is clicked so something like this should work:

```
$args = array('type' =>'comments','callback' => 'mytheme_comment');
if (isset($_GET['comOrder']) && $_GET['comOrder'] == 'Newest' )
    $args['reverse_top_level'] = true;
wp_list_comments($args);
```

Comment: well, thanks for that, but i dont have foreach, i have wp_list_comments('type=comments&callback=mytheme_comment'). mytheme_comment is my customised function in functions.php file. So should i put your code before that wp_list_comments function?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: i did use your last updae but still not working. is it something wrong in my mytheme_comment function ? is it possible for you to login to wp site and have a look at the code? :)

Comment: i dont mind to pay :)

Comment: sorry man its working. i put 'comments' in parameter, it should be 'comment'. thanks man. but now how about displaying comments in oldest to newest ?

Comment: ok, sorted out oldest to newest. just put reverse_top_level false